# Sideways label for table with alternating row colours

Tags: tables, color, multirow

I have a multirow column in a longtable with alternating coloured rows. The alternating colour overflows into the multirow. Colouring the first column white wipes out the specialrule but doesn't seem to make a difference to the row colour. I am not sure how to deal with this. Would you have any pointers?

Here is my MWE:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{longtable, booktabs, rotating, multirow}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\definecolor{tblue}{HTML}{F1F5FA}
\definecolor{tgrey}{HTML}{dddddd}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.6}
\usepackage{arydshln}
\arrayrulecolor{tgrey}
\begin{document}
\rowcolors{1}{tblue}{white}\centering
\begin{longtable}{>{\columncolor{white}}l !{\color{white}\vrule width 4pt}>{\raggedright}p{3in} p{2.4in}}
\hiderowcolors
&\textbf{Selected representative vars}&\textbf{Correlated vars ($\rho \ge$ 0.8)}\\
\specialrule{0.01em}{0.02em}{0.02em}
\endhead
\specialrule{0.01em}{0.0em}{0em}
\endfoot
\specialrule{0.01em}{0.0em}{0em}
&\multicolumn{2}{l}{\textbf{Subheading}}\\
\specialrule{0.01em}{0.0em}{0em}
\showrowcolors
& Something & Something else
\\
& Something & Something else
\\
& Something & Something else
\\
\hiderowcolors
\specialrule{0.01em}{0.0em}{0em}
&\multicolumn{2}{l}{\textbf{Subheading}}\\
\specialrule{0.01em}{0.0em}{0em}
\showrowcolors
& Something & Something else
\\
& Something & Something else
\\
& Something & Something else
\\
\multirow{-9}{*}{\begin{sideways}\centering \textbf{A long line of sideways text}\end{sideways}}
\end {longtable}
\end{document}
```

Here is what the table looks like currently:
[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A different way of thinking: Insert the vertical text using zero-width boxes, rather than giving its own column.

[image]

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{longtable, booktabs, graphicx, multirow}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\definecolor{tblue}{HTML}{F1F5FA}
\definecolor{tgrey}{HTML}{dddddd}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.6}
\usepackage{arydshln}
\arrayrulecolor{tgrey}
\begin{document}
\rowcolors{1}{tblue}{white}\centering
\begin{longtable}{!{\color{white}\vrule width 4pt}>{\raggedright}p{3in} p{2.4in}}
  \hiderowcolors
  \textbf{Selected representative vars}&\textbf{Correlated vars ($\rho \ge$ 0.8)}\\
  \specialrule{0.01em}{0.02em}{0.02em}
  \endhead
  \specialrule{0.01em}{0.0em}{0em}
  \endfoot
  \specialrule{0.01em}{0.0em}{0em}
  \multicolumn{2}{l}{\textbf{Subheading}}\\
  \specialrule{0.01em}{0.0em}{0em}
  \showrowcolors
  Something & Something else \\
  Something & Something else \\
  Something & Something else \\
  \hiderowcolors
  \specialrule{0.01em}{0.0em}{0em}
  \multicolumn{2}{l}{%
    \llap{\smash{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{%
      \hspace*{2\normalbaselineskip}% Vertical adjustment
      \textbf{A long line of sideways text}}}%
      \hspace*{\dimexpr\tabcolsep+2em}}% Horizontal adjustment
    \textbf{Subheading}}\\
  \specialrule{0.01em}{0.0em}{0em}
  \showrowcolors
  Something & Something else \\
  Something & Something else \\
  Something & Something else \\
  %\multirow{-9}{*}{\begin{sideways}\centering \textbf{A long line of sideways text}\end{sideways}}
\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

The sideways text is rotated using `\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{..}` from [`graphicx`](http://ctan.org/pkg/graphicx) (also included when using [`rotating`](http://ctan.org/pkg/rotating)). `origin=c` pivots the rotation around the `c`entre of the object. `\llap` create a `l`eft over`l`ap, pushed outward by `\tabcolsep+2em`. This effectively places the sideways text `2em` from the left margin of the `longtable`. Also, since I chose an element not exactly in the middle (vertically) of the table, pushing it upward by `2\normalbaselineskip` allows for proper vertical alignment with the rest of the table's body (8 rows).

`\smash` removes all vertical height + depth from an object, thereby not affecting the row height.

Comment: It works most beautifully! With your code, I added several sideways labels without the need for adding a whole column and altering my pre-existing tables! Thanks so very much for this solution!! :-)

Answer (score 3):

The latest version of `nicematrix` (v 5.8 of 2021-01-01) has dedicated tools to deal with that problem.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{tblue}{HTML}{F1F5FA}
\definecolor{tgrey}{HTML}{dddddd}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.6}

\begin{document}
\centering
\begin{NiceTabular}{l>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{3in}p{2.4in}}%
  [rules/color=tgrey, code-before = {\rowcolors{3-5,7-9}{tblue}{}[restart,cols=2-]} ]
&\textbf{Selected representative vars}&\textbf{Correlated vars ($\rho \ge$ 0.8)}\\
\Hline
\Block{*-1}<\rotate\bfseries>{A long line of sideways text}
&\Block[l]{1-2}{\textbf{Subheading}}\\
& Something & Something else \\
& Something & Something else \\
& Something & Something else \\
\Hline
&\Block[l]{1-2}{\textbf{Subheading}}\\
& Something & Something else \\
& Something & Something else \\
& Something & Something else \\
\Hline
\end{NiceTabular}
\end{document}
```

You need several compilations (because `nicematrix` uses PGF/Tikz nodes).

[image: Output of the above code]