# Sideways (rotated 90 degrees) label for table

Tags: tables, rotating

How can I create the following table in LaTeX? I created the table below using PowerPoint.

[image]

Here is my best attempt at using LaTeX to create the table:

```
\begin{tabular}{l|l|l|}
  \cline{2-3} 
  & \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{Returning Week} \\ \cline{2-3}
    & 1 & 2 \\ \hline
  \multicolumn{1}{|l|}{1} & 0.3 & 0.2 \\ \hline
  \multicolumn{1}{|l|}{2} & 0.1 & 0.1 \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
```

and the output

[image]

Similar tex.stackexchange posts:

- [Sideways label for table with alternating row colours](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/56787/sideways-label-for-table-with-alternating-row-colours) includes a more extensive example of a table that includes this feature, but it is hard to parse because it includes many other features.
- [How to make table with rotated table headers in LaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/98388/how-to-make-table-with-rotated-table-headers-in-latex?rq=1) likewise has a table with many many entries, so is hard to parse as well

Comment: From the first linked question, all you need is the `rotating` package and its `sideways` environment. Please add your code for the table (without the rotated label, of course).

Comment: @karlkoeller Done! It does look ugly that the columns 1 and 2 have different widths. How should I fix that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{rotating}
\begin{document}
\raisebox{-.2in}{\rotatebox{90}{Arriving Week}}
\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.2}
\begin{tabular}[b]{p{0.8in}|p{0.8in}|p{0.8in}|}
  \cline{2-3} 
  & \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{Returning Week} \\ \cline{2-3}
    & 1 & 2 \\ \hline
  \multicolumn{1}{|l|}{1} & 0.3 & 0.2 \\ \hline
  \multicolumn{1}{|l|}{2} & 0.1 & 0.1 \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Similar to Steven's solution, but reproduces almost exactly the table in your image.

You have to compile it with `xelatex`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures=TeX}
\setmainfont{Calibri}

\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.15}

\begin{document}

\raisebox{-1.4cm}{\rotatebox{90}{Arriving Week}}\hspace{3pt}
\begin{tabular}{|p{2.5cm}|p{2.5cm}|p{2.5cm}|}
  \multicolumn{1}{l}{}  & \multicolumn{2}{l}{\hspace{1.1cm}Returning Week} \\ \cline{2-3}
  \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} & 1 & 2 \\ \hline
  1 & 0.3 & 0.2 \\ \hline
  2 & 0.1 & 0.1 \\ \hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can easily construct that tabular with `{NiceTabular}` of `nicematrix`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}

\begin{NiceTabular}{*{3}{w{c}{2cm}}}[first-col,first-row,hvlines,corners=NW]
& & \Block{1-2}{Returning week} \\
\Block{3-1}<\rotate>{Arriving week}& & 1 & 2 \\
& 1 & 0.3 & 0.2 \\
& 2 & 0.1 & 0.1 \\
\end{NiceTabular}

\end{document}
```

You need several compilations (because `nicematrix` uses PGF/Tikz nodes).

[image: Output of the above code]